# PowerBI Matrix subtotals incorrect when using DISTINCTCOUNT DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, report, dashboard

I am trying to build a matrix in PowerBI and have created a new measure for my value field:

PSUs = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(ARPU[DistinctNumber])) to count distinct values, but the subtotals are not correct with this method. I am using groupings and sub groupings in my Rows. Images are attached.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcV5w.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fZ7o.png)

So far, I have tried numerous DAX formulas, creating a new table of the data I need, and removing my filters but have had no luck. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I hope you're not expecting the totals to default to a sum, because they won't; they will apply the same aggregation as that for the individual entries, i.e. a distinct count.

Comment: Thank you, Jos. Do you have any suggestions for what I can do differently if I needed the sum?

Comment: It can be done, though it would be useful to see a small, copiable sample dataset together with expected results. Dummy data is fine, a dozen or so rows' worth.